# Unable to read arbitrary files through XML file parser

Tags: php, xml, xslt

So I've wanted to create a very basic **XML** file parser that imports **XML** styles.

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);

$XSLT = new XSLTProcessor();
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();

$XSL->load($_GET['file']);
$XSLT->importStyleSheet($XSL);

print $XSLT->transformToXML($XML);
```

Now I need to read an arbitrary file like this:

```
http://localhost/parser.php?file=style.xml
```

Given that I find it hard to troubleshoot as to why I cannot seem to read a **.txt** file on the local filesystem in the same directory.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('message.txt')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `document()` function requires well-formed XML. You can't use it to read a *plain text document*. Try using it to read an XML document in the same directory. It should work:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('message.xml')"/> <!-- message.xml is well formed XML -->
```

Comment: I need to read a .txt file, that's the problem. Can this be done through XML?

Comment: You need to read a txt file inside a stylesheet? What does it contain?

Comment: No a separate, independent .txt

Comment: It doesn't make sense. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Test for a vulnerability. I saw an example of reading system files on a UNIX box like .htpasswd and I began to wonder how that might be possible.

Comment: Actually, I got it solved. The error that it was outputting was containing part of the file's content.

Comment: You can insert arbitrary text in XML files using entities: `<!DOCTYPE [ <!ENTITY somefile SYSTEM "file.txt"> ]>` which refers to a file in the same directory, and then use `&somefile;` inside the XML to insert the data. Of course, it may generate malformed XML.

Comment: Yeah, I got it working that way anyhow. Thanks for your time :)